# LoadingTemplate timeOut function - Iron & Meteor

Tags: meteor, iron

I would like to know how I could force loading template to have a minimum load time (ex: 3 seconds) before loading my default template / controller (App Controller). I have no subscriptions so, the only thing I need is to set the timeout for delaying the loadingTemplate.

I've already tried a similar solution posted [here][1] but the problem now is that Router.route('/', { name: 'home'}); is never called and I'm stuck on the loadingTemplate page.

I deployed my application to http://ns-timeout.meteor.com/ so anyone could have a look on my console.logs()...

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thank you very much

```
Router.configure({
 layoutTemplate: 'AppController',
 loadingTemplate: 'loading',
 waitOn: function() {
    var hasWaitTimePassed = new ReactiveVar(false);
    var waitFor = 3000; // Wait for 3 sec
    var stopped = false;

    Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('setTimeOut() hasWaitTimePassed :'+  hasWaitTimePassed.get());
        console.log('setTimeOut() stopped :'+  stopped);
        if (!stopped) {
            hasWaitTimePassed.set(true);
            console.log('setTimeOut() if(!stopped) : hasWaitTimePassed.set(true):'+  hasWaitTimePassed.get());
            console.log('setTimeOut() if(!stopped): '+  stopped);
        }
    }, waitFor);

    return {
        ready: function() {
            // hasWaitTimePassed is a reactive source, so this should do just fine
            console.log('return { ready function() hasWaitTimePassed :'+  hasWaitTimePassed.get());
            console.log('return { ready function() stopped :'+  stopped);
            return hasWaitTimePassed.get();
        },

        stop: function() {
            console.log('return { stop function() hasWaitTimePassed :'+  hasWaitTimePassed.get());
            console.log('return { stop function() stopped :'+  stopped);
            // Stopping should prevent the hasWaitTimePassed becoming true.
            stopped = true;
        }

    };
  }

});
```